# Transmission of http call data to composte child

Tags: angular, http

First of all, excuse my English, I'm using a translator.

I'm having trouble passing the data from an http request to a child component.

First I get the data using two services and that part works fine.

servicio-principal.service.ts

```
llamadaGet(url2: string, datosLlamada: any) {

    return this.http.get(ServicioPrincipal.myUrl+url2, datosLlamada);

}
```

servicio-secundario.service.ts

```
getDatos () {

    const myParametros = {parametro1: 'texto1', parametro2: 'texto2'};
    
    return this.sesionServ.peticionGet('textoUrl/texto', myParametros);
    
}
```

Then I call them from a component and by doing a `console.log` the data is shown, but I send it to a child component and there it is not seen (in the child component).

componente1.component.html

```
<componente-hijo [datos]="myDatos">
```

componente1.component.ts

```
constructor(private servicioPrincipal: ServicioPrincipal, private servicioSecundario: ServicioSecundario) {

    this.ServicioSecundario.getDatos()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data); // Here if the data is shown
      this.myDatos = data;
    });

}
```

componenteHijo.component.html (This is where the data is not displayed)

```
<p *ngFor="let registro of datos">{{registro.campo1}} {{registro.campo2}}</p>
```

componenteHijo.component.ts

```
@Input() datos: any[] = [];
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.datos);
}
```

If you sent raw data to the child component (without making an http request) if it is displayed.

Editing: When you do ngOnChanges() the data is displayed in the child but not passed to the view.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered that the eroor was not related to the so called http, but to the fact that the data shown in the view is filtered by a function and that this function must be called with every change of the source data in order for it to be updated:

componenteHijo.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let registro of _datos">{{registro.campo1}} {{registro.campo2}}</p>
```

componenteHijo.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.filtro();  
    
}

filtro() {

   this._datos = this.filtrado.transform(this.datos,this.palabra);

}

ngOnChanges() {

    this.filtro();

}
```

And to make it more efficient

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.datos && changes.datos.currentValue) {
      this.filtro();
    }
}
```